Multidimensional Oracle database Array in PHP issue
issue with the code is that it writing the last row in loop only (in the file) , where as it should display all data fetched from database.
however the echo function does print out all data
but fputcsv write only last row
script
include 'includes/connection.php';
            $date = date('d-M-Y');

            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1
            LCM.something1

            FROM  DB.something1 LCM
    
            WHERE LCM.something1 = 'ASAS' ";

            $array = oci_parse($conn, $query);
            $run = oci_execute($array);
    

        while($row=oci_fetch_array($array)){

        $CMCF06 = $row[0] ;
            $CMCF08 = $row[9] ;
        $CMCF09 = $row[12];
        
        echo $CMCF06 .'<br>';

      
        $data = [
            ['HDHD', '2C4L20018', $date, $date, '081054','002'],
            ['CMCF', '2C4L20018', '', '0100', '',$CMCF06, '', $CMCF08, $CMCF09],
                ];
        
    


        $filename = 'file.csv';
        
        // open csv file for writing
        $f = fopen($filename, 'w');
        
        if ($f === false) {
            die('Error opening the file ' . $filename);
        }
        
        // write each row at a time to a file
        foreach ($data as $fields) {
            fputcsv($f, $fields, '|');
        }
        
        }
        echo 'done<br>';
        // close the file
        fclose($f);

I tried while loop and foreach loop but still same problem

If you indent your code correctly you can more easily see where your while { ... } loop starts and ends. You'll notice that you restart creating the file every time.

Your query is pointless as there will only ever be a single row returning ASAS (in multiple columns with the same identifier), just use SELECT LCM.something1 FROM  DB.something1 LCM WHERE LCM.something1 = 'ASAS' AND ROWNUM=1


Format your code neatly so that the indentation matches the level for each (nested) control statement.
Don't re-open (and re-create) the file in each loop. Create the file once at the start and then write to it within the loop.
Don't SELECT the same column repeatedly from the database (as it is pointless). I am assuming that you have redacted your query and you should be selecting from different columns.

You want something like this (untested):
include 'includes/connection.php';
$date = date('d-M-Y');

$filename = 'file.csv';
        
// open csv file for writing
$f = fopen($filename, 'w');
        
if ($f === false) {
  die('Error opening the file ' . $filename);
}

fputcsv($f, ['HDHD', '2C4L20018', $date, $date, '081054', '002'], '|');

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT
       LCM.something1
       LCM.something2
       LCM.something3
       LCM.something4
       LCM.something5
       LCM.something6
       LCM.something7
       LCM.something8
       LCM.something9
       LCM.something10
       LCM.something11
       LCM.something12
       LCM.something13
       LCM.something14
       LCM.something15
FROM   DB.something1 LCM
WHERE  LCM.something1 = 'ASAS'";

$array = oci_parse($conn, $query);
$run = oci_execute($array);

while($row = oci_fetch_array($array)) {
  $CMCF06 = $row[0] ;
  $CMCF08 = $row[9] ;
  $CMCF09 = $row[12];
        
  echo $CMCF06 . '<br>';

  fputcsv($f, ['CMCF', '2C4L20018', '', '0100', '', $CMCF06, '', $CMCF08, $CMCF09], '|');
}

echo 'done<br>';

// close the file
fclose($f);


If you only want data from certain columns then use:
$query = "SELECT something1, something10, something13
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         LCM.something1
         LCM.something2
         LCM.something3
         LCM.something4
         LCM.something5
         LCM.something6
         LCM.something7
         LCM.something8
         LCM.something9
         LCM.something10
         LCM.something11
         LCM.something12
         LCM.something13
         LCM.something14
         LCM.something15
  FROM   DB.something1 LCM
  WHERE  LCM.something1 = 'ASAS'
)";

then:
$CMCF06 = $row[0] ;
$CMCF08 = $row[1] ;
$CMCF09 = $row[2];


If you provide an answer try to show good code. That means not selecting columns that aren't used. Watch your spacing, it's inconsistent. Can you also explain point 3 a bit better? Which same column? Don't just copy into an answer what you read in the comments.

@KIKOSoftware The columns ARE important to SELECT even if the OP does not output them - the OP uses SELECT DISTINCT on a list of columns if you do not select all of those columns then you will get a different set of results.

As for point 3, the OP uses SELECT something1, something1, something1 and selects the same thing over and over. I am assuming that they have redacted their query and they should all be different column names (because they are expecting multiple rows of output - if they were not expecting multiple rows of output then the DISTINCT query would only return a single row).

OK, I see your point, you're probably right. If you edit while($row=oci_fetch_array($array)){ then your answer is perfect.
